# How to pass JSON to server in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, express, quill

I'm creating a blog using ExpressJS, MongoDB, and QuillJS for rich text Editor.
I'm trying to pass Delta (QuillJS JSON Object to server via ajax)

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
  var delta = quill.getContents();
  console.log(delta)
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      delta: delta
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
  })
})
```

Here is my server

```
articleRouter.post('/new', async function(req, res) {
    let article = new Article({
        type: 'blog',
        title: req.body.title,
        hook: req.body.hook,
        content: req.body.delta,
        writer: req.body.writer
    })
    try {
        article = await article.save()
        res.redirect(`read/${article.slug}`)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.render('index', { page: 'new', article: article, title: 'Create a new article' })
    }
})
```

and Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const slugify = require('slugify')

// Define collection and schema
let Article = new Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    hook: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    content: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    },
    writer: {
        type: String
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}, {
    collection: 'article'
})

Article.pre('validate', function(next) {
    if (this.title) {
        this.slug = slugify(this.title, { lower: true, strict: true })
    }
    next()
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', Article)
```

I got this error

```
Error [ValidationError]: Article validation failed: content: Path `content` is required.
```

I believe that the AJAX is not working properly or I miss something at:

**content: req.body.delta,**
How can I fix this?

Comment: looks like your ajax url should be pointing to `http://localhost:3000/new` instead of `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: I think the error is coming from MongoDB. You probably haven't mentioned `content` in your model. Can you also post your model definition.

Comment: As @JoeLissner mentions, it seems that you are pointing at the wrong end point. I would suggest attaching a debugger and adding some breakpoints to see where your code is executing.

Comment: What does `console.log(delta)` print? Also you could try doing a `console.log(req.body)` in the server route. Please provide the results for both. It seems that the value you are passing in for `content` is `undefined` or null, and that is what MongoDB is complaining about, as `content` is a required field.

Comment: @RachitAnand `console.log(delta)` returns `delta` as JSON. `console.log(req.body)` returns all `title, hook, writer` of the form but not `content` which is `delta`. You are right, `content` is either `undefined` or `null`. I tried to change ajax url but still didn't work

Comment: You will have to check what `quill.getContents()` does. Apparently it is not returning the `content` part in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mongoose to connect to MongoDB? If so, check your `Article` Schema. Maybe `content` is a required field.